# Get the sum for unique fields

Tags: mysql, select, sum

Suppose I want to get ID, price and SUM(price) so it should look like:

```
ID    price    sum
--------------------
 1     10      
 1     10      20
 2     20      
 2     20      40
 3     30
 3     30      60
```

What is the way to achieve this? My real query:

```
SELECT users.login, projects.name, time_entries.issue_id, time_entries.hours
FROM users, time_entries
INNER JOIN projects ON time_entries.project_id = projects.id
WHERE time_entries.spent_on = CURDATE() - 1
AND time_entries.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY users.login;
```

Shows

```
+-------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+-------+
| login | name                                               | issue_id | hours |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+-------+
| ach   | name1                                              |    12624 |     8 |
| aco   | name2                                              |    11550 |     3 |
| aco   | name2                                              |    11585 |     3 |
| alt   | name3                                              |    12644 |   7.5 |
| ata   | name4                                              |    12761 |     1 |
| ata   | name5                                              |     NULL |     1 |
| ata   | name6                                              |    12790 |   0.5 |
| ata   | name7                                              |    12677 |   5.5 |
| ato   | name8                                              |    12530 |     8 |
| elb   | name8                                              |    12697 |     1 |
| elb   | Software management                                |    12678 |     7 |
```

I want to get sum of hours in fifth column for unique login.

Comment: The data you're showing doesn't match the data you need (i.e. there is no "price" column). Also, does your output need the rows that have empty sums? Or, was the "what it should look like" general and not directed at your exact data?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for here is [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
SELECT
    users.login, SUM(time_entries.hours) AS hours
FROM
    users
    JOIN time_entries ON time_entries.user_id = users.id
WHERE
    time_entries.spent_on = CURDATE() - 1
GROUP BY
    users.login
```

This would give output similar to:

```
login    hours
--------------
 ach     42
 alt     13
 ata     27
```

If you want to include the `issue_id` column, as per your sample output they can differ, you may be interested in `GROUP_CONCAT()` which will pull in a comma-separated list of each issue that the given user has had:

```
SELECT
    users.login,
    GROUP_CONCAT(issue_id) AS issues,
    SUM(time_entries.hours) AS hours
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.login, projects.name, time_entries.issue_id, SUM(time_entries.hours) as hours
FROM users, time_entries
INNER JOIN projects ON time_entries.project_id = projects.id
WHERE time_entries.spent_on = CURDATE() - 1
AND time_entries.user_id = users.id GROUP BY users.login
ORDER BY users.login;
```

Answer (score 0):

newfurniturey, thanks for your answer and thanks others too.
That is the nearest I'm looking for:

```
SELECT users.login, GROUP_CONCAT(projects.name),
GROUP_CONCAT(time_entries.issue_id),
GROUP_CONCAT(time_entries.hours), SUM(time_entries.hours) as hours 
FROM users, time_entries 
INNER JOIN projects ON time_entries.project_id = projects.id
WHERE time_entries.spent_on = CURDATE() - 1 
AND time_entries.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.login ORDER BY users.login;

    | ata   | name1,name2,name3 | 12761,12790,12677 | 1,1,0.5,5.5 | 8 |
```

But I would like to get next result if it possible:

```
| ata   | name1 | 12761 | 1   |   |
| ata   | name2 | 12790 | 1   |   |
| ata   | name3 | 12677 | 0.5 |   |
| ata   | name3 | 12677 | 5.5 | 8 |
```

or

```
| ata   | name1 | 12761 | 1   |
| ata   | name2 | 12790 | 1   |
| ata   | name3 | 12677 | 0.5 |
| ata   | name3 | 12677 | 5.5 |
| ata   |       |       |     | 8 |
```